# "Attempted to update project that is not loaded" error in VSCode

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just started my Unity 2D course on udemy, but my vs code keep throwing error. After I open my script on VS Code, a message box show up and says, "Some projects have trouble loading. Please review the output for more details." And with that, I'm unable to work with IntelliSense.

Here is the OmniSharp server log:

```
    Starting OmniSharp server at 22.09.2022 14:12:59
    Target: c:\Users\Mehmet Akif\Experimenting\Experimenting.sln

OmniSharp server started with .NET 6.0.401
.
    Path: c:\Users\Mehmet Akif\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.25.0-win32-x64\.omnisharp\1.39.2-beta.26-net6.0\OmniSharp.dll
    PID: 18012

[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Starting OmniSharp on Windows 10.0.19043.0 (x64)
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        Checking the 'DOTNET_ROOT' environment variable to find a .NET SDK
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        Using the 'dotnet' on the PATH.
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        DotNetPath set to dotnet
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Located 1 MSBuild instance(s)
            1: .NET Core SDK 6.0.401 17.3.1 - "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.401\"
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Registered MSBuild instance: .NET Core SDK 6.0.401 17.3.1 - "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.401\"
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.CSharpFormattingWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 0
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        Detecting projects in 'c:\Users\Mehmet Akif\Experimenting\Experimenting.sln'.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for 'c:\Users\Mehmet Akif\Experimenting\Assembly-CSharp.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Detecting CSX files in 'c:\Users\Mehmet Akif\Experimenting'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Did not find any CSX files
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Configuration finished.
[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Omnisharp server running using Stdio at location 'c:\Users\Mehmet Akif\Experimenting' on host 8552.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: c:\Users\Mehmet Akif\Experimenting\Assembly-CSharp.csproj
[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1 için başvuru bütünleştirilmiş kodları bulunamadı. Bunu çözmek için, bu çerçeve sürümü için Geliştirici Paketi'ni (SDK/Hedefleme Paketi) yükleyin veya uygulamanızı yeniden hedefleyin. .NET Framework Geliştirici Paketleri'ni https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks adresinden indirebilirsiniz
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Failed to load project file 'c:\Users\Mehmet Akif\Experimenting\Assembly-CSharp.csproj'.
c:\Users\Mehmet Akif\Experimenting\Assembly-CSharp.csproj
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.401\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1220,5): Error: .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1 için başvuru bütünleştirilmiş kodları bulunamadı. Bunu çözmek için, bu çerçeve sürümü için Geliştirici Paketi'ni (SDK/Hedefleme Paketi) yükleyin veya uygulamanızı yeniden hedefleyin. .NET Framework Geliştirici Paketleri'ni https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks adresinden indirebilirsiniz

[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Attempted to update project that is not loaded: c:\Users\Mehmet Akif\Experimenting\Assembly-CSharp.csproj
[warn]: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.InlayHints.InlayHintService
        Inlay hints requested for document not in workspace Location { FileName = c:\Users\Mehmet Akif\Experimenting\Assets\Driver.cs, Range = Range { Start = Point { Line = 0, Column = 0 }, End = Point { Line = 18, Column = 0 } } }
[warn]: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.InlayHints.InlayHintService
        Inlay hints requested for document not in workspace Location { FileName = c:\Users\Mehmet Akif\Experimenting\Assets\Driver.cs, Range = Range { Start = Point { Line = 0, Column = 0 }, End = Point { Line = 18, Column = 0 } } }
```

I've tried to install SDK 7.0 and add "latest" to omnisharp.path on VS Code. But problem still exists.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Alright fixed.

If you are facing with this problem: `Error: .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1` ,

Just click [this](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/thank-you/net471-developer-pack-offline-installer) link to install 4.7.1 dev pack. Install and reboot VSCode.